# CLOSED - How to get resolved DNS IP from python twisted reactor?

Tags: python, dns, twisted

I am trying to create a resolving DNS server using python twisted.  I am wanting to do a domain lookup and then manipulate (or at least parse) the returned look-up value. Here is what I have done so far:

```
from twisted.names import client, dns, server, error
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

class DNS_Reslover(object):
    def __init__(self, rsvr):
        self.__resolver = rsvr

    def dump(self, obj):
        for attr in dir(obj):
            if hasattr(obj, attr):
                print("obj.%s = %s" % (attr, getattr(obj, attr)))

    def _qryCallBack(self, qry):
        # print(qry)
        print(len(qry))
        for i in qry[1]:
            print(i)

    def _qryError(self, domainname):
        print("error {}".format(domainname))

    def query(self, query, timeout=None):
        """
        Check if the query should be answered dynamically, otherwise dispatch to
        the fallback resolver.
        """
        _d = self.__resolver.lookupService(query.name.name)
        _d.addCallback(self._qryCallBack)
        _d.addErrback(self._qryError)

        return defer.fail(error.DomainError())

def main():
    """
    Running server
    """
    client_resolver = client.Resolver(resolv='/etc/resolv.conf')
    factory = server.DNSServerFactory(clients=[DNS_Reslover(client_resolver)])

    protocol = dns.DNSDatagramProtocol(controller=factory)

    reactor.listenUDP(5553, protocol)
    reactor.listenTCP(5553, factory)
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    raise SystemExit(main())
```

What is returned is

```
<RR name=google.com type=SOA class=IN ttl=59s auth=False>
```

I am interested in parsing and validating the IP address but it is not being retuned.  Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: The IP address is not being returned because you get back a `SOA` record either because you asked for it (look in your library documentation to find out how to ask for `A` or `AAAA` records) or because this is really what remote server replied with, which can happen for example for names that don't exist. So no matter what your code needs to first check the resource record type given before trying to get the IP address in it, if it is really an A/AAAA record. And handle those cases depending on your needs (report a problem? retry something else? etc.)

Comment: Thank you for what you have posted.  The lookup was for an SOA, I am shaking my head.  Again you rock.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have since added `_d = self.__resolver.getHostByName(_query_name, timeout=None, effort=10)`.  This returned the resolved IP address.   This was what I was looking for.  Thanks and this can be closed